# Node.js / Express: POST being turned into GET (code 302)

Tags: node.js, http, express, passport.js, passport-local

In brief, I have a login page where my `POST` request is turning into a `GET` in Express 4.

Here is the business part of my login page:

```
<form id='loginForm' action='/login' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type='submit'>Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here are routes I set:

```
// Express 4    
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('./login.hbs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/welcome',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}));

passport.use('local-login',
    new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, email, password, next) {
            User.findOne({ 'authLocal.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            console.log('Inside local-login strategy with findOne A');
            [snip]
```

I put a breakpoint on the `res.render` for `GET /login` and in the `findOne()` call in the `local-login` strategy.  When I click on the "Submit" button the breakpoint that catches things is in the `router.get()` code.

In the debugger the `req.method` is `GET`.

In the browser (Chrome) I'm told that I'm doing a POST to `/login` that returned 302. There is also a pending `GET` to `/login` with a 200 code.  These two codes (302, 200) are when the debugger stops in `router.get()`.  Even clearing the browser cache doesn't help.

Can someone tell me why my `POST` request isn't being honored?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer**

Reason behind `POST /login` being turned into `GET /login 302` is the redirection done by passport module.

See `failureRedirect` in following code:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/welcome',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

It can happen when credentials provided are invalid or server fails to authenticate for any reason.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the strategy is `local` not `local-login` according to [this documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#authenticate-requests).

It also, looks like the first argument to the `passport.use` function should be the LocalStrategy object, not a string.

Give that a try!

Comment: passport.use(label, object) is legal. From  http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/ :  Strategies used for authorization are the same as those used for authentication. However, an application may want to offer both authentication and authorization with the same third-party service. In this case, a named strategy can be used, by overriding the strategy's default name in the call to use().

passport.use('twitter-authz', new TwitterStrategy({...  My code is using the "name it yourself" variant.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies.  Are you still having this issue?

Comment: I scrapped my code and started over with the example based on scotch.io. I no longer have that issue. I can't mark this result as an "answer" for this Q, though, because some monitor on this site will mark it as an inappropriate answer.

Comment: Also, because I didn't actually answer your question!  I'm glad to hear this is no longer an issue, though I am still curious what was happening.

Comment: I'm curious too, but no longer have the pressure to get an answer.  Thanks for replies.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, does anybody got any solution?