# My mongoose collection not saving the passed data on to the database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I created my schema using mongoose but the collection is not saving the passed data onto the database as a matter of fact the collection is on the database list of collection

The model is

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MovieSchema = new Schema({
 description: String,
 category: String,
 token:  String,
 fileID: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 }
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movies', MovieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;
```

while logistic on saving the documents is

```js
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    
      
    const movie = new Movie({
        description: req.body.Description,
        category: req.body.Category,
        token: req.body.Description,
        fileID: req.file.id 
    })
    movie.save(function(err){
      if(err){
           console.log(err);
           return;
      }

      res.json({ "success": "true"});
});
 
});
```

```
if i console.log(movie) i can see the objects
```

Comment: Hi! Do you see an error on the console, or do you get a successful response?

Comment: No error on the console neither success

Comment: Do you get a 500 Internal Server Error if you look up the request in the "Network" tab of your developer tools? If so, that may be because you don't have a body parser.

Comment: Not the status is 302

Comment: Do you use something like Passport? I'm wondering if your issue could be [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599167/node-js-express-post-being-turned-into-get-code-302).

Comment: No i used Multergridfs-storage

Comment: it didn't work any suggestion?

Comment: I'm using multer gridfs storage to upload a file then i reference the fileID from my schema above with the file i'm uploading so as once i uploaded a file to a collection content a movie collection can also be added

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: No i just deleted everything then i wrote the i code again although i used the one you pasted here. Then it works but couldn't figure the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the same setup as you did:

- Express
- Multer
- Multer GridFS Storage
- Mongoose

It seemed to work (got `{ success: true }` response and stuff stored in the db), as this excerpt from a `mongo` console session shows:

```
> db.movies.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c02a7ccfe06f6644fc891e7"), "fileID" : ObjectId("5c02a7ccfe06f6644fc891d5"), "__v" : 0 }
> db.fs.files.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c02a7ccfe06f6644fc891d5"), "length" : 4265368, "chunkSize" : 261120, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2018-12-01T15:25:00.411Z"), "filename" : "d32a3c421f8b7bb1654f2abe13e9cf0f", "md5" : "c6203a2cfee5169a8c90015b99bb7844", "contentType" : "image/jpeg" }
```

Here are my files.

#### Main Express app file

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moviesRouter = require('./routes/movies');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/movies');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/api/movies', moviesRouter);

app.listen(8000);
```

#### Movies model (same as you)

```
// models/Movie.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MovieSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    category: String,
    token:  String,
    fileID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movies', MovieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;
```

#### Movies route (mostly your code too)

```
// routes/movies.js
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer');

const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require('../models/Movie');

// Create a storage object with a given configuration
const storage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/movies'
});

// Set multer storage engine to the newly created object
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

  const movie = new Movie({
    description: req.body.Description,
    category: req.body.Category,
    token: req.body.Description,
    fileID: req.file.id 
  });
  movie.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    res.json({ "success": "true"});
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

#### HTML test page

Located under `public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>StackOverflow mongoose/gridfs question</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <form id="movie" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <label for="file">Choose movie</label>
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />

      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <script>
      const status = document.getElementById('status');
      const form = document.getElementById('movie');
      const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
      console.log(fileInput);
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/api/movies');
        request.onload = function(event) {
          if (request.status == 200) {
            status.innerHTML = 'Sent!';
          } else {
            status.innerHTML = `Error: ${request.status}`;
          }
        };

        request.send(formData);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since I do not have your whole code, it's hard to know where the problem lies precisely:

- Is your mongo database set up ? (with e.g. `use movies;`)
- Is it a problem with the way data are encoded when you sent them to the server (you should have `multipart/form-data` encoding, see screenshot)
  [image: StackOverflow mongoose/multer gridfs post]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I started separate project then copied your code, the magic works

Comment: now is just that if i try populating the movie i got using the fileID i got undefined